# How to get names, ids and types of inputs of a certain form

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, let's suppose that I know the id of a post where I have a certain form.

Using PHP, how can I get the id, type and name of all the inputs of this form?

Comment: How is the form submitted? Are you using an Ajax call or are you directly posting it to some php file?

Comment: Hi,
Actually, the form is created by the plugin WPFORMS, but it's just a detail, because I'm looking for a generic way to get the details of the inputs of the form (id and type) just by knowing the id of the page where the form is located.